# Check certain existing objects in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I have a pretty simple problem with Java, but explaining it is not a simple as i expected. Basically, I want to check if any objects from a certain class exist. An example:

I have a class Animal, and I have two subclasses, Cat and Dog. And when running the program, I want to know if any dogs or cats exist. I know I created a dog, OR a cat, but I don't know which. I could check all cats and dogs that I created in my previous code if they exist or not, but it's not only an ugly, but also a dumb solution.

So, is there a nice way to know if there are any dogs or cats that currently exist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can we see the code please?

Comment: Do your animals have a method by which they explicitly stop existing? Do you need access to the dog and/or cat objects themselves, or is it good enough to know that some exist?

Comment: Is what you want to do is ask the JVM "Do any objects of type T exist?"

Comment: Sorry, but the code is too big for the question format, in my opinion... So if you think I should dump 100+ lines of code here, I will do it, but I tought it has no use.

Comment: @DoraHerbert why do not you use InstanceOf ?

Comment: @TedHopp No, they get created or they do not get created. It's enough if there is any existing.

Comment: @KickButtowski I know that a dog is an animal. I just don't know if it exist currently or not.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Yes, exactly.

Comment: @DoraHerbert may be you should look for the content of dog. if it exists do not add and if it does not , do add :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a real simple approach...

Assuming Cats and Dogs never die (as my children would wish), then each class can have a static counter.

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  private static int liveOnes = 0;

  public Dog() {
    liveOnes++;
  }

  public static int getHowManyAlive() { return liveOnes; }
}
```

You can then check if any dogs exist by using

```
Dog.getHowManyAlive() > 0
```

If they do die, then you need to explicitly kill them and decrement the count.

Comment: Using static is really ugly as well (and not OO at all) : it is not a Dog's property to know how many Dogs are alive. I would rather use a DogFactory (factory design pattern), instantiate it then increment a counter within the factory.

Comment: Yes, a factory would be a more elegant solution but I was going for simple.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using the factory DP :

```
public class DogFactory {

  private int producedDogsCount;

  public DogFactory() {
    this.producedDogsCount = 0;
  }

  public Dog produceDog() {
    this.producedDogsCount++;
    return new Dog();
  }

  public int getProducedDogsCount() {
    return this.producedDogsCount;
  }
}
```

Then to produce dogs you need the factory :

```
DogFactory dogFactory = new DogFactory();
```

and need to call the `produceDog()` method :

```
Dog myDog = dogFactory.produceDog();
```

In order to know how many dogs you have produced you ask the dog factory :

```
int producedDogsCount = dogFactory.getProducedDogsCount();
```

Note that this allows you to have different counters depending on the characteristics of the dogs you produce (for instance if your factory allows you to choose the color, race, character, size of the dog to be produced)